# signalR client hangs on wait()

Tags: c#, signalr-hub, signalr.client

SignalR client hangs on `wait();`
Here is my code

```
Proxy.Invoke<string>("IO_Table_Game_Status", getTableGameStateJsonReq).ContinueWith((responseJson) =>
{
    string tablestatusResp = responseJson.Result;
}).Wait();
```

Here I need to get the Json value in `tablestatusResp`. But it's showing empty value.

Comment: What context is this running in? If you are in an ASP.NET or WinForms (or other GUI) setting, calling `Wait()` on a `Task` that is being run on a thread pool thread will deadlock your application since only one thread can be active at a time (since the Wait call is blocking, the thread pool thread can't return the control). Also, I'm confused as to why you are declaring a local variable in the lambda, it will go out of scope on the line after and have done you no good.

Comment: it is a winForms.Casino Game developing in WPF and C#

Comment: In that case, see my answer. `Wait()` is blocking the UI thread, preventing the background thread from returning control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data=Proxy.Invoke<string>("IO_Table_Game_Status", getTableGameStateJsonReq).Result;
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: `Result` is a blocking call the same way `Wait()` is, this may be "cleaner" in a sense, but if OPs code deadlocked before, it will still deadlock with this code, I am pretty sure.

Comment: yes,i think some thing is wrong in method “IO_Table_Game_Status” ！

Comment: What makes you think that? If that was the case, `Wait()` would have surely thrown an `AggregateException`?

Comment: I mean the results are not expected.

Comment: This is to be expected since it was stated that the `Wait()` invocation deadlocks, indicating that `Result` never returns.

Answer (score 1):

Since (from what I can tell) SignalR is exposing access to a true asynchronous operation (looks like it's sending HTTP messages), I think it'd be best if you let your application leverage this asynchronicity. It makes for easier to maintain and understand code, and it saves you from the bajillion pitfalls when it comes to deadlocks on blocking calls when using the Wait method and it's siblings.

```
public async Task<TReturnType> YourCurrentMethod()
{
    var tableStatusResp await Proxy.Invoke<string>("IO_Table_Game_Status", getTableGameStateJsonReq);
}
```

Note that the method signature is made up by me, all you have to do is to mark it as `async` so you can use the `await` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Finally i got answer to my question... i have used Dispatcher. here is the code

```
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
                {
                  string  tablestatusResp = Get_Info_Panel_Proxy.Invoke<string>("IO_Table_Game_Status", getTableGameStateJsonReq).Result;
                }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this when my hub was not being initialized correctly. Try to create a raw Hub, with a clean constructor and a simple method to see if it keeps hanging.